# curl underlining head output

Tags: bash, curl, manjaro

`curl` started acting strange for me in last few days, its double underscoring when reading headers:

[image]

With `-i` it just double-underscores everything after header as well:

[image]

When just reading body it outputs as expected:

[image]

I have tried `-IX GET` as well just to rule off `HEAD` request, it was same. Worth noting also, I use `guake`, tho I have tried default terminal and it acts same.

**Further troubleshooting**

- Created new user, tested with it to avoid profile changes Ive made,
  still an issue.
- Tried from TTY, does not underline but prints out light blue letters where there would be underline in terminal.
- Curl version = `curl 7.61.0`

Googling is not helping much, stuck at the moment, any ideas?

Comment: it wont show underlines @Jesse_b

Comment: Seems like it may be an issue with your terminal application

Comment: tried default terminal, usually using guake @Jesse_b

Comment: Is your `PS1` supposed to be underlined?

Comment: not that I know of, this only happens so far with `curl` @jeremysprofile

Comment: Version? Does it happen in TTY? Create a new user and try and reproduce...

Comment: `curl` version: `curl 7.61.0`, new user > same; TTY > does not underline but paints it light blue where it should be white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [release notes for curl 7.61](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2018-07/0004.html) note the following new feature:

> curl: show headers in bold, switch off with --no-styled-output

The comments on the [linked pull request](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/2538) suggest the double underlining you and I am seeing is the result of a bug in this feature where the "boldness" is not being turned off properly. It is possible that the changes in https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/2738 will fix this in a future curl version.